# Set a custom title for all pages in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I enabled the configuration variable "SubPages" in my MediaWiki.
Now I would like the following markup to be automatically placed on all pages.

```
{{DISPLAYTITLE:{{SUBPAGENAME}}}}
```

In general, I want to customize my title pages.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [mw.config](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript#mw.config) has no access to subpage name, but in your custom JavaScript you could still use [mediaWiki.message](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Modules#mediaWiki.message) to parse a custom string like your `{{DISPLAYTITLE:{{SUBPAGENAME}}}}` and then replace it to the title and main h1.

This is a bit silly though, you could look into BookManager extension and other Wikisource/Wikibooks tricks to see how they handled subpages at scale.